# c# Dictionary with Func<string, T> als values

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I want to put Func where T is a generic type as values in a dictionary. So Basically I want to do something like:

```
 Dictionary<string, Func<MyObject, T>> _sortMappings = 
                new Dictionary<string, Func<MyObject, T>>()
    {
        { "Name", (b) => b.Name }, // name is a string            
        { "Length", (b) => b.Length }, // length is an int
        { "Date", (b) => b.Date } // a datetime object
    };
```

Does this make sense and is this possible?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `Func<T, string>`? A `string` doesn't have the property `Name`, nor `Date` - so the lambda's don't even qualify as a `Func` that takes `string` and returns `T`.

Comment: You're right. It is an object of a custom defined class. Corrected it.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible with `Func<MyObject, T>` you need to use `Func<MyObject, object>`. T can't be more than one type at the same time. So you need to find a common type for `string`, `int` and `DateTime` which is `object`.

Comment: Indeed, object seems the way to go, but I was looking for a more elegant way without need for boxing/unboxing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way using [Convert.ChangeType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

`"Name", b => (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(b.Name,typeof(T))`

your function should be

```
private static T InvokeFunction<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
       Dictionary<string, Func<MyObject, T>> sortMappings =
       new Dictionary<string, Func<MyObject, T>>();
       sortMappings.Add("Name", b => (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(b.Name,typeof(T)));
       sortMappings.Add("Length", b => (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(b.Length, typeof(T)));
       sortMappings.Add("Date", b => (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(b.Date, typeof(T)));
       return func.Invoke();
    }
```